# HTML code of a page

Tags: html, wordpress

i have a question about this page: https://www.webovo.nl/blog/.
When i inspect something on the website, i get to see a lot of html and css code. I understand i can find the css in the style.css file, but i don't know where i can find (and edit) the html code i'm seeing. Where (and how) can i see the source of the html code i'm seeing?

For example, i wanted to change the default text that u can see in the search field (which is: zoeken ..). I can't find that piece of code anywhere.

I'm using Onepress theme.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried: view-source:https://www.webovo.nl/blog/? In the URL. This dumps the source of the page.

Comment: Are you trying to edit your own site or temporarily change the code of a third party site?

Comment: This is my own site. So i want to edit it in Filezilla or Wordpress Editor. But i dont know where i can find this html document

Answer (score 1):

The search field in the Onepress theme is added in file template-parts/content-none.php (line 23 and 28) by this code:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

This refers back to [wp-includes/general-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c2d709e9d6cbe7f9b3c37da0a7c9aae788158124/wp-includes/general-template.php#L192) where the search form is either included from the template, if a "searchform.php" exists, or it is built like this (line 192):

```
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" />
```

Your placeholder text "Zoeken ..." is inserted here:

```
esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' )
```

Then again the text "Zoeken ..." is pulled from a translation file that you have in your Wordpress installation. Changing these files is a bit "dangerous" in the sense that they might be overwritten by future updates.

That said, there is an easy way to get a custom search with custom text: Create your own searchform.php. You can, for example, just take the file from the twentyeleven theme: [searchform.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dd6da701b286579819cd6aa518aa2d7018efd759/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/searchform.php). Copy this file into your Onepress theme folder, change the `placeholder` attribute and you are done.

```
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Whatever" />
```

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: Nice, seems like a great solution!

Comment: Thanks youre my hero!

Answer (score 0):

If this is your site, it's this section.

[image]

However, I cannot suggest you where to look inside the HTML files, since I cannot view the structure of the files :).

Please review this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i know how i can edit it with inspect element but not how to edit it in the source so its stays... You know what i mean? haha

Comment: Well, which editor are you using? And are you, or are you not the owner of this website?

Comment: This is my website, and what do you mean by editor? Mostly i edit some code in the Wordpress Editor or i use Filezilla to look up the document. But i cant find the document where i can find the placeholder thing.

Comment: The parent element is called widget-area sidebar with the id secondary. So I suspect you would find it in a file called sidebar or something.

Comment: https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/onepress/1.2.9/sidebar.php sooo.. sidebar-1 probably.

Comment: https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/onepress/1.2.9/functions.php It seems to be some built-in thing for Wordpress. Cannot help you with it any further. @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/#registering-a-sidebar

Comment: I've found 2 documents with the search option: https://s16.postimg.org/vdphdpnwl/image.png & https://s16.postimg.org/n9hd8z1hh/image.png https://s16.postimg.org/9tucjiszp/image.png i dont see the placeholder thing.

Comment: Second image, inspect the get_sidebar() function. Where does that go?

Comment: Also, just download all the files, then search them with: https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/download

Comment: get_sidabar goes tot: sidebar.php: if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
 return;
}
?>

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area sidebar" role="complementary">
 <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what browser you are using. However, for Chrome upon right clicking and inspecting an element there will be a **Styles** and a **Computed** tab which shows the CSS for the element. On the Styles tab you can see where the style has been inherited from.

For the search bar you can see that the style was inherited from style.css on line 80.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i know that, but where can i adjust it in my code so it goes 'live'?

Comment: The website needs to be yours in order to edit the live version. If it's not you can use CTRL+S to make a local copy of the website which you can edit on your machine. However, if the website is yours and you have access to the web server you can find the styles sheet at

Comment: wp-content/themes/onepress/style.css or you can go to your wordpress admin and change the style sheet there

Comment: CSS is the style of the elements, it will allow you to change the font style, etc. However, the text itself 'zoeken' is HTML. You can edit that by going into the same folder where the css is stored, there will be a blog folder or blog.php which you can edit and will contain all the HTML for the document.